# resource controller with two arguments

Tags: laravel

I have a resource which is defined (in the real world) by two parameters. Let's take the car-analogy: I'd like a resource accessible as follows:

```
/cars/{model}/{make}
```

I know I can create a controller for this and routes pointing to it, but I cannot figure out how to do this with a resource route:

```
Route::resource('/cars', 'CarController');
```

This will create routes with only one parameter:

```
GET/HEAD  cars            App\Http\Controllers\CarController@index
POST      cars            App\Http\Controllers\CarController@store
GET/HEAD  cars/new        App\Http\Controllers\CarController@create
GET/HEAD  cars/{car}      App\Http\Controllers\CarController@show
PUT/PATCH cars/{car}      App\Http\Controllers\CarController@update
DELETE    cars/{car}      App\Http\Controllers\CarController@destroy
GET/HEAD  cars/{car}/edit App\Http\Controllers\CarController@edit
```

where the `{car}` parameter is referring to the database key.

Is it possible to create a resource route utilizing the two parameters `{make}` and `{model}` (and if yes: how)?

Or do I have to resort to manually creating all routes?

I'm using Laravel 5.5, if that's of any difference.

To be clear, I'd like to end up with:

```
GET/HEAD  cars                     App\Http\Controllers\CarController@index
POST      cars                     App\Http\Controllers\CarController@store
GET/HEAD  cars/new                 App\Http\Controllers\CarController@create
GET/HEAD  cars/{make}/{model}      App\Http\Controllers\CarController@show
PUT/PATCH cars/{make}/{model}      App\Http\Controllers\CarController@update
DELETE    cars/{make}/{model}      App\Http\Controllers\CarController@destroy
GET/HEAD  cars/{make}/{model}/edit App\Http\Controllers\CarController@edit
```

The `edit` function (for example) will then look like:

```
public function edit(string $make, string $model) {
    // sort out DB entry and provide it to a view
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a trait that looks up the corresponding make,model-combination to a car?

Comment: Looking up the model is not the issue here, it's about getting the parameters from a (user friendly) url to the controller.

Comment: I understand that, but because you don't want to type the extra paramter declaration 7 times (which if this is the only controller, this should be no problem at all) you could create a function that you can re-use for this situation is all I'm saying.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this idea in an answer with some pointers on how to implement? I do not yet see how/where the trait is used to end up with only one declaration in the routes/web.php file. Typing 7 routes out is indeed no big issue, but I'd like the file to be readable. Having a single resource-route communicates "this is a regular resource".

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more: instead of writing `public function edit(string $make, string $model) {` You might be better of using 1 function to combine them inside the controller: `getcar ($request){ return lookup($request->model, $request->make) }`

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159378/resource-controller-with-two-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource routing does not want to be setup this way. You could do nested resource but that would still add a segment between what you would like for parameters there.

Define the routes yourself; `Route::resource` just registers 7 routes you can always register explicitly yourself.

The closest I can get:

```
Route::resource('cars.model', 'CarsController', [
    'parameters' => ['cars' => 'make']
]);

cars/{make}/model/{model}
```

Comment: Although the docs do not show a way to do it, they neither explicitly say it can't work. Seeing your take on this confirms my expectation that manual routes are required. Thanks. Unless someone comes up with something else, you have my vote...

Comment: yes, the docs don't say that you could create your own `ResourceRegistrar` and use that to create any format of uri that you would like when registering resource routes.

Comment: Nested resources is indeed not the way to go because of the extra segment. Extending `ResourceRegistrar` seems to have a learning curve _too_ steep for this project alone (especially because I can't find any docs/pointers on what to extend exactly and where to start). I will go with the seven route declarations and add a comment on why it's not one resource-declaration.